# Disable trackpad when mouse is plugged in - Windows 7 Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, mouse, macbook, touchpad

I just installed Windows 7 64-bit on my Macbook Pro. I would like the trackpad to be disabled when I plug in a USB mouse. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

[TrackpadMagic](http://www.pocketlim.com/TrackpadMagic/) does this. Per the author, versions "newer than 5/26/2009 are tested on Windows 7 x64 on Santa Rosa Macbook Pro, older versions tested on Windows XP. Unibody Macbook Pro tested on Windows Vista."

It requires the .NET framework, links are supplied on the page.

Screenshots from their page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: doesn't work on my win 7 macbook pro

seems the case for another user as well here: http://superuser.com/questions/149145/macbookpro-running-windows-7-accidental-trackpad-input-is-driving-me-mad

it's not even seeing the mouse I have plugged in.

Comment: I cant answer because I don't have enough reputation, but here is how it worked for me : Go to Device Manager -> Mice and Other Pointing Devices. You will find there multiple devices. Double Click each one of them and disable the one that has the location set as "on Apple Multitouch". Make sure you can see the connected mouse as one of the other pointing devices