# MacBookPro running Windows 7: accidental trackpad input is driving me mad

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, touchpad, input

I am running Windows7 Professional 64bit on a 2010 MacBookPro using BootCamp 3.1.
I am using an external trackball.
When I am typing, I accidently brushing the trackpad and accidently overtyping randomly selected pieces of text. Which is driving me mad.

I have tried to install TrackPad++, but I could not get the Trackpad++ control panel to recognise that the driver software was installed.

I tried TrackPad Magic, but although it gives me a system tray icon telling me it is working, but it does not appear to disable the track pad.

A quick Google implies that there *should* be an option in the BootCamp Control Panel 'Ignore accidental Input while typing'.
But I can't see one of those in my BootCamp Control Panel.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is this feature 32bit only? 
Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did.  Open Device Manager (Click Windows, then type in Search programs and files: device manager)

Go to Mice and other pointing devices, you will see you have two HID-compliant mouse.  Those are your mouses/trackpads/trackballs. Disable each one of them, check which one is your built-in trackpad or external trackball

If you accidentally disabled your external trackball, navigate the mouse pointer using the built-in trackpad, then re-enable the one(external trackball) you mistakenly disabled.  Then disable the other one

Comment: that is ridiculous.  So if this works, Apple couldn't make sure that their freakin hardware shows up with a proper name in Windows?  Nice.

Comment: @user23511, very few plug and play devices show up with their "actual" names in Windows, even on a native Windows machine. It is hardly Apple's fault.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a new 2010 Macbook Pro, W7 X64, Bootcamp 3.1.

Trackpad++ sodtware, which I've discovered last week, works GREAT for me. The option to ignore accidental input is very, very useful. The scrolling now behaves very much like in OS X. Couldn't be better.

I assume you haven't followed the instructions on how to install the Trackpad++ thing. Maybe you didn't disconnect your external trackball during driver install, or, even worse, installed trackpad driver onto trackball device? Since we have the same HW and SW and for me T++ works, while for you it doesn't, then you did something wrong! Make sure than in the device manager, the trackpad device name is the same as on my screen capture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal but since there's no easy way to turn the trackpad on/off, I've been setting an old CD on the trackpad. Until a better solution is found, this works as a good 'switch'.

Answer (score 0):

I just came here to find a solution to deactivate the Trackpad on a MacBook Pro 2015 running Windows 10 over BootCamp while using an external mouse.

We can use System Device Manager to deactivate the Apple multi-Touch Trackpad but I'm not happy with this solution (what if I had to go on meeting room without having an external mouse o_O' ).

Then I look a bit and find a better solution using [TrackPad++](http://www.trackpad.powerplan7.com/).

Note that it's not a perfect solution :

- You need to install first [Power Plan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/home.htm) wich turns off 64 bits signed driver validation (!!!)
- You need to perform a 5 fingers click to reactivate the trackpad

But at least It's doing what I need.

Answer (score -1):

There is a utility called [Touchfreeze](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/auto-disable-mouse-touchpad-when-typing/) and another called [Touchpadpal](http://www.pcworld.com/article/204693/Disable_Your_Laptops_Touchpad_While_You_Type_Windows_7_Edition.html) that may work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.