# How to disable my netbook's touchpad when a usb mouse is connected

Tags: windows-7, mouse, netbook, touchpad

This is the first computer I have ever bought and I couldn't bring it home without a mouse of its own. I'm trying to disable the touchpad but the only option I find is by uninstalling the drivers, which I think is a bit drastic, the buttons for activation and deactivation are disabled (I'm using windows 7 starter).

Do you have any idea of how to disable the touch pad when an external mouse is hooked up?

Comment: See also [Disable trackpad when mouse is connected (Dell laptop)](http://superuser.com/questions/185995/disable-trackpad-when-mouse-is-connected-dell-laptop)

Comment: http://public.madeinengland.co.nz/how-to-disable-the-touchpad-when-usb-mouse-is-plugged-in/ there if anyone needs it - offers the option via the registry or GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the driver you have, if it is an Synaptics touchpad, you can disable it by right clicking on the taskbar icon.

For Alps, I think you can do it from the mouse properties in Control Panel.

For anything else, or different versions, just hunt around a mix of the above - either the mouse options or taskbar icon.

Comment: Some Synaptics touch pads also have a gesture of some sort to disable them. For mine (HP ProBook 4720s) I can double tap the upper left corner to disable/enable it.

Answer (score 4):

Click Synaptics tray icon, select "Pointing Device Properties"; select "Device Settings"; you can either disable it, or, in Windows 7, have it disable automatically if you connect an external mouse.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to Windows 7, but in Windows 10 there's a built in option to disable the touchpad when a mouse is connected.

Open the [Windows 10 settings app](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-10-ways-open-settings) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), navigate to ***Devices → Touchpad***, and uncheck ***Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected***

[image: Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected]