# How to disable touchpad when external mouse is connected

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad

In [How to disable my netbook's touchpad when a usb mouse is connected](https://superuser.com/questions/242118/how-to-disable-my-netbooks-touchpad-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected) I could not find an answer for my question.

Some laptops have drivers that automatically disable touchpad when an external mouse is connected. My three-years-old Toshiba's drivers do not have such option. Is there another way to do this in Windows 7? Answers to the mentioned question say to use the driver's option. I don't have that driver and thus don't have such option. What can I do?

Comment: See also [Disable trackpad when mouse is connected (Dell laptop)](http://superuser.com/questions/185995/disable-trackpad-when-mouse-is-connected-dell-laptop)

Comment: I'm looking for third-party software for this too; Acer's India tech support took 20 minutes to tell m e they THINK it's synaoptics and they refuse to support Windows 7. "PowerSwitch" is great for laptops and I'm hoping to find a third party program like that but for the trackpad ONLY when mouse is hooked up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable my netbook's touchpad when a usb mouse is connected](https://superuser.com/questions/242118/how-to-disable-my-netbooks-touchpad-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected)

Comment: The suggested duplicates do not appear to provide a Win 7 solution if the driver doesn't support this feature, as is the case here.

Comment: @John Why in the world did you decide to choose to call acer india tho?? Also still need the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't apply to Windows 7, but Windows 8 & 10 have a built in option to disable the touchpad when a mouse is connected.

Open the [Windows settings app](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-10-ways-open-settings) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), navigate to ***Devices → Touchpad***, and uncheck ***Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected***

[image: Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected]

Answer (score 0):

I havn't seen or know of a program which does this, but [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will allow you to automate what Shree said about...