# disable touchpad when mouse is connected windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I want to disable my touchpad when my mouse is connected.
Google gives me [lots](https://superuser.com/a/1216703/770497) of [answers](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-touchpad-while-mouse-connected-windows-10) that seem really straightforward.

Only problem is the suggested option is not available for me:
[image: touchpad settings windows]

I'm using windows 10 on an MSI laptop.
Other suggestions how I can achieve this?
I can still manually disable my touchpad trough fn + f3.

Answer (score 2):

We can try the following two ways:

1. Right click on the Synaptics Pointing Device icon located on the taskbar
2. Click on Pointing Device Properties
3. Tick on the option Disable internal pointing device when external USB pointing device is attached
4. Click on OK
5. Now, view if the touchpad won’t bother you again when you are using your mouse.

Source: [How to Disable Touchpad on MSI Laptop Automatically When An External Mouse is Connected](https://www.techwalls.com/disable-msi-touchpad-using-mouse/)

1. Open your "Start" menu and click "Control Panel." If you don't see it, look for it under "Settings."
2. Click on "Mouse" under "Hardware and Sound."
3. Select the "Touchpad" tab and look for "Touchpad settings" or something aptly named.
4. Select "Disable," click "Apply" and then "OK" to save your settings.
5. View if the touchpad is disabled.

Source: [How to Disable the Touchpad on an MSI](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-touchpad-on-an-msi)

Comment: I'm going to search more thoroughly later but for now it seems that in both ways there are options missing for me.
Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: There IS a checkbox there, half way down the page on the last tab (labeled 'Elan' on my HP laptop, since that's the OEM's formal device name for the HP "Clickpad")