# Why do I get random page scrolls in VIM (gvim)?

Tags: vim, gvim, scrolling

I often find that I am editing away then gvim randomly does a page scroll. which means I start typing in the wrong place. On the basis that its most likely to be user error, is there some key combination that I am inadvertently pressing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on MacOS Sierra by any chance? Maybe you're suffering from this [trackpad sensitivity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670984/vim-scrolling-with-touchpad-too-sensitive), if I understand correctly, the problem being that OS 10.12 generates more, finer-grained (?) scrolling events. Apparently the Java folks discovered the [same issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166591). No solution that I know of unfortunately. Maybe time to raise a Vim bug?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of keys that can move you around in `normal` mode, but not so much in `insert` mode. If you're moving around in `insert` mode randomly, you should check your `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc` for any `insert` mode keymappings (see: [`imap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-modes)).

Some of the commonly used navigational keys in `normal` mode are

<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> => `<left><down><up><right>`

<kbd>H</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> => `Top, Mid, Bottom of current display`

<kbd>zt</kbd><kbd>zz</kbd><kbd>zb</kbd> => `Set row that cursor is on to Top, Mid, Bottom of page`

`<number>`<kbd>gg</kbd>/<kbd>G</kbd> => `Go to row <number>`

`<number>`<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> => `Go <number> columns/rows left, down, up, right`

.. so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

### It might not be a key combination at all.

I find that random scrolling around within entryfields, not just within text editors, happens to me frequently on laptops where the touchpad is enabled, as the heel of my hand accidentally touches the touchpad.  I'm far from the only one to have experienced this.  [This person suffered from this problem too](https://superuser.com/questions/185995/), as did the person answering in all-capitals.

If you discover that this is your problem, the simple solution is of course to turn the touchpad off.  The hard part, as can be seen from that question and the number of ["How do I disable the touchpad?" questions in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Btouchpad%5D%20disable), is doing that.  ☺

Comment: its definitely not that in this case because I am using my laptop as a desktop with a keyboard and a mouse (and the touch pad is switched off).